# How To Control Dropdown Select Options Menu With Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am creating a web site. In this web site there is a form and user has to input details. So , in this form , I have added 2 dropdowns like below. Now I want, when I select number 9 from Adults menu, I want to disable children menu. Otherwise if the number is 8 or less than 8, still user can select from children menu. Then I used length in jquery. But, that not what I want.

How can I do this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var adults = parseFloat($('#adults').val());
  var children = parseFloat($('#children').val());
  var infants = $('#infants').val();
  var Total = adults + children;
  //$("#errorModal").html(Total);

  $('#adults').change(function() {
    var st = $('#adults option:selected');
    if (st.length > 8) {
      $("#children").prop('disabled', true);
    }
  });

  alert(Total);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="signupForm">

  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 hero-feature">
    <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
    Adults :
    <select name="adults" class="form-control" id="adults">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
    </select> <br>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 hero-feature">
    <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
    Children :
    <select name="children" class="form-control" id="children">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
    </select> <br>

  </div>

  </div>

  <a href="#" id="ghsubmitbtn" class="btn btn-success">Search Flight Data</a>

</form>
```

Comment: you don't need to use length as up to 0-9 value length is 1, so use value so your code "st.length > 8" change to "st.val() > 8"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to change length to

```
 if (st.val() > 8)
```

DEMO: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/ERpXOa

To enable back when value is different:

```
if (st.val() > 8)
{
     $("#children").prop('disabled', true);
}else{
     $("#children").prop('disabled', false);
}
```

Comment: Yeah , It's Working now.. And also when I click it once , children will be disabled. And after that again when I click 8 or less than 8 , I want to enable children menu. How can I do it ??

Comment: I have already done it in fiddle. you just need to add else condition. check in fiddle

Comment: Okay , got it.. Thank U !!

Comment: I need your help again -
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51028333/how-to-control-input-type-dropdown-select-options-menu-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

You should check against the selected value, not the length:

```js
var adults = parseFloat($('#adults').val());
var children = parseFloat($('#children').val());
var infants = $('#infants').val();
var Total = adults + children;
//$("#errorModal").html(Total);

$('#adults').change(function() {
  if (this.value > 8) {                     // check against the value of the adults drop down
    $("#children").prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $("#children").prop('disabled', false);  // probably need to re-enable it
  }
});

// alert(Total);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="signupForm">

  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 hero-feature">
    <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
    Adults :
    <select name="adults" class="form-control" id="adults">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
    </select> <br>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 hero-feature">
    <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
    Children :
    <select name="children" class="form-control" id="children">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
    </select> <br>

  </div>

  </div>

  <a href="#" id="ghsubmitbtn" class="btn btn-success">Search Flight Data</a>

</form>
```

Comment: Yeah , It's Working now.. And also when I click it once , children will be disabled. And after that again when I click 8 or less than 8 , I want to enable children menu. How can I do it ??

Comment: Ahh I changed it to (this.value == 9). Then it worked only once. That why I asked.. my bad.. sorry.. BTW Thnak U !!