# How To Control Input Type Dropdown Select Options Menu With Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a web site. In this web site , there is a form. I have added 3 dropdown menus in this form like below. Now I want to when someone selects the number 5 from Adults menu , I want to show number 5 in the infants menu. And also I want t keep Adults + Children = 9. Then if this Total is below than 9 , I want to show that extra number in the infants menu. I mean like this ,

```
Adults + Children = 9
Adults = 5 and infants = 5
But , Adults + Children = 8
Adults = 5 , Children = 3 , it means there is still 1. 
Now I want to show that 1 with infants , 1 + 5 = 6.
```

look below snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var adults = parseFloat($('#adults').val());
  var children = parseFloat($('#children').val());
  var infants = $('#infants').val();
  var Total = adults + children;
  //$("#errorModal").html(Total);

  var totalAdultChild = 9;
  $('#adults').change(function() {
    var adultValue = this.value;
    if (this.value > 8) {
      $("#children").prop('disabled', true);

    } else {
      $("#children").prop('disabled', false);

      $('#children option').each(function(index, element) {
        if ((totalAdultChild - adultValue) < this.value)
          $(this).hide();
        else
          $(this).show();
      });

      $('#infants option').each(function(index, element) {
        if (adultValue < this.value)
          $(this).hide();
        else
          $(this).show();
      });

    }
  });


  //alert(Total);

});
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="signupForm">

  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 hero-feature">
    <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
    Adults :
    <select name="adults" class="form-control" id="adults">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
    </select> <br>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 hero-feature">
    <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
    Children :
    <select name="children" class="form-control" id="children">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
    </select> <br>

  </div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 hero-feature">
<!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
Children :
<select name="infants" class="form-control" id="infants">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
</select> <br>

  </div>

  <a href="#" id="ghsubmitbtn" class="btn btn-success">Search Flight Data</a>

</form>
```

No Answer ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution as per your explanation:

```
$('#children').change(function() {
    var children = $('#children').val();
    var infants = $('#infants').val();
    var adults = $('#adults').val();
    var total_pending;
   if((parseInt(adults) + parseInt(children)) < totalAdultChild){
     total_pending = totalAdultChild - (parseInt(adults) + parseInt(children));
     new_infants = parseInt(infants) + parseInt(total_pending);
     $('#infants').val(new_infants);
   }
 });
});
```

DEMO: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/aKaJxW

Comment: Almost got what I need. But , if adult + children = 8. it means still we can add 1 to get 9 as the total. Then infants can be 6. extra 1 goes to infants. That what I need.. How can do it ?? If adults = 5 , infants = 5. but with that extra 1 , infants = 6.

Comment: so what i have done is select adults = 5 , infants = 5 and children =3, it will change the infants to 6.

Comment: Nop , it didn't. Adults = 5 , Children = 3 , infants could be 5 or 6. or it will be 0. and also children could be 0. It depends on the user. Either he can select 5 , 6 or 0 from infants. and also any number from children less than total 9.

Comment: and what if . Adults = 5 , Children = 2?

Comment: Its not compulsory to change those values. If the user wants , he can change those values. The default value for the adult is 1 , children & infants = 0. But , in the dropdown I want to show values under those rules as I mentioned above.